# How to read .sql file format

Tags: sql, sql-server, r

I have a database which is (example.sql) and I would like to read it in RStudio for further analysis, how could I do this function?

Comment: Try with `read.csv.sql` from `sqldf`.  For more info, check [here](https://github.com/ggrothendieck/sqldf)

Comment: I've already try it but it does not work !

Comment: Okay, `it does not work` is not very informative.

Comment: Is it an `sql server management` file.  Another option is using `ROBDC` i.e. `library(RODBC) ;
cn <- odbcDriverConnect(connection="Driver={SQL Server};server=localhost;database=yourdatabase;trusted_connection=yes;")` then use the `sqlQuery` to get the data.

Comment: sorry !  let me share the error hold on please !

Comment: I got this ! Warning messages: ````
1: In odbcDriverConnect(connection = "Driver={SQL Server};server=localhost;database=sms.sql;trusted_connection=yes;") :
  [RODBC] ERROR: state 08001, code 17, message [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]SQL Server does not exist or access denied.
2: In odbcDriverConnect(connection = "Driver={SQL Server};server=localhost;database=sms.sql;trusted_connection=yes;") :
  [RODBC] ERROR: state 01000, code 2, message [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]ConnectionOpen (Connect()).

Comment: It depends on whether you have an `SQL Server` database or not.

Comment: Yes i have microsoft sql management server studio 2016

Comment: anyway, it works for me.  BTW `database = sms`

Comment: wow you must be my supervisor   thanks

Comment: No am serious you right db=sms how do you know ??

Answer (score 1):

One option is using `RODBC`

```
library(RODBC)
cn <- odbcDriverConnect(connection="Driver={SQL Server};server=localhost;database=sms;trusted_connection=yes;")
```

and then use `sqlQuery` to read the lines.